# jQuery Supersized image not displayed within html5boilerplate website

Tags: jquery, supersized

I'm trying to implement the jQuery plugin [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) (3.2.6) into a blank [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) (3.0) website but I don't get it to work:

Images are not displayed although all necessary files are loaded (including script, style and some sample images). I figured out that the image (inside div with `id="supersized"`) has the css attribute `display: none`. When I remove this from style sheet everything looks fine and the images are displayed. But I don't think, that this is the right way because I changed the default style which should be OK:

```
    #supersized img{ width:auto; height:auto; position:relative; display:none; outline:none; border:none; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that `display:none` is only located inside [slideshow supersized.css](https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized/tree/master/slideshow/css) but not inside [supersized.core.css](https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized/tree/master/core/css). I thought both core and slideshow examples are using the same core stylesheet. So I guess, I have to use supersized.core.css when I don't want to build a slideshow.

Comment: When I want to build a slideshow, I have to use [slideshow supersized.css](https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized/tree/master/slideshow/css), right? But in this case, the images are not displayed.

Comment: I don't know, I never used supersized. I added that comment based on the CSS code you posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself: For slideshow I have to use the script from slideshow example. I thought it isn't a different script because it is named the same. My fault. And btw. this is no issue regarding to html5boilerplate. Sorry for that.